# Sarxos api webcam issue

Tags: api, webcam

I am trying to access webcam by using `sarxos api` for webcam. When I run the program, I get the `JNI` error and exception in main thread like this:

> NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/sarxos/webcam/WebcamPanel

How can I solve that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved this error on my own. this was caused by not calling the open function  of the webcam. i was trying to capture without opening the stream from webcam.